# Symfony set `createdBy` and `modifiedBy` properties of entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I want to automatically set the `createdBy` and `modifiedBy` properties of an entity.

To set these properties I use the doctrine lifecycle hooks `prePersist` and `preUser`as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-callbacks.
I also created a `setCreatedByValue` and `setModifiedByValue` functions to set the fields ...

Is there any best practice on how to write the currently logged-in user into these properties?
Is there a let's say "more elegant" way than injecting the security service into the entity?

How would you do that?

Comment: Probably best to use a [Doctrine Entity Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners) and inject the security service into it.  There are also several `blamable` bundles out there that implement this sort of thing.  Trying to inject stuff directly into an entity is always a bit problematical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now searched through the Symfony docs once again and chose the following approach for me:

I created an `EntitySubscriber` as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers

After that, I created two interfaces `TimestampInterface` (for `createdAt` and `modifiedAt`) and a `UserAwareInterface` (for `createdBy` and `modifiedBy`).
I also created an `AbstractEntity` that implements the interfaces mentioned above. Now I can extend each entity (which needs this functionality) with the `AbstractEntity` class ...

Then I simply created a `doctrine.event_subscriber` (as described in the docs) and checked for the interfaces to set certain fields.

To set the `createdBy` and `modifiedBy` fields I used the Security container.
Works pretty well - and with this solution, I don't rely on any third-party libs.

```
<?php 

namespace Foo\Bar\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PrePersistEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Foo\Bar\Entity\TimestampInterface;
use Foo\Bar\Entity\UserAwareInterface;

class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        public Security $security,
    ) {}

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::prePersist,
            Events::preUpdate
        ];
    }

    public function prePersist(PrePersistEventArgs $prePersistEventArgs): void
    {
        $object = $prePersistEventArgs->getObject();

        if($object instanceof TimestampInterface){
            $object->setCreatedAt(time());
            $object->setModifiedAt(time());
        }

        if($object instanceof UserAwareInterface){
            $object->setCreatedBy($this->security->getUser()->getId());
            $object->setModifiedBy($this->security->getUser()->getId());
        }
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $preUpdateEventArgs): void
    {
        $object = $preUpdateEventArgs->getObject();

        if($object instanceof TimestampInterface){
            $object->setModifiedAt(time());
        }

        if($object instanceof UserAwareInterface){
            $object->setModifiedBy($this->security->getUser()->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about that solution?

Comment: Oddly similar to what I suggested in the comments.  So a big plus one from me.  You might want to check that Security::getUser returns an actual user just in case the entity somehow manages to get updated when the user is not logged in.  Probably should not happen but no sense in having an exception get tossed.

Comment: @Cerad yeah thanks for pointing me in the right direction 

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand you the excellent [Gedmo listeners](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions), it's exactly what you want.

### Tracking which user edited your entity the last time

Have a look at [this documentation](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/blameable.md).

##### Bonus an updatedAt: DateTime field

You can have the same behavior with an `updatedAt` field that you could want to fill automatically, you have [this extension](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/timestampable.md) that do the job for you. This isn't required

Let me know if something isn't clear

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will have a look at it. But IMHO it feels a kind of "wrong" to install a third party library just for such a small thing. This should be 5 to 10 lines of code - i think installing a third party lib is kind of overkill or?

Comment: In my experience the best selling point for Gedmo is `SoftDeleteable`. If you don't need that then it's probably overkill (in some cases it may even take more time to set up than it would to make the listener yourself)

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing wrong with installing an external library for this usecase. I know what the library does because I'm used to it. The library is tested, it allow you to remove complexity from your own code. It is a matter of choice. This package solve very common problems when designing an application. Of course you can code the listener yourself, it'll be faster, just be carefull with edge cases ;)